# Active Admin batch edit products with a preset collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

Is there a way to add batch edit to Active Admin with a preset collection? My product model contains a `category` field.

My ActiveAdmin's form looks like this :

```
f.input :category,as: :radio, collection:['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']
```

So I can choose a category within a collection. I would like to add batch edit so I could check many fields and then assign them a category from the previous collection.

My first idea was to add many batch actions (one for cat1, one for cat2, one for cat3, etc. However, the batch actions menu would then contain more than 10 elements...

There must be a better way to do this, is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may render custom view and post changes to category from there, using your own action. 
Something like this:

In `admin/product.rb`

```
batch_action :set_category do |selection|
  if (@products = Product.where(id: selection)).blank?
    redirect_to :back, flash: {error: "No products were selected!"}
  else
    render template: 'products/edit_group_category' #, layout: 'some_custom_layout' - I had some problems trying to use active_admin layout here, but custom one works fine (you may need it for styling)
  end
end
```

In `views/products/edit_group_category.html.haml`

```
=form_for :group_category, url: :update_group_category do |f|
  -@products.each do |product|
    =f.hidden_field :products, :multiple => true, :value => product.id

  =f.input :category, as: :radio, collection:['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']

  =f.submit 'Submit'
```

In `controllers/products_controller.rb`

```
def update_group_category
  products = Product.where(params[:group_category][:products])

  #set here category with name params[:group_category][:category] to all of products

  redirect_to '/admin/products', notice: 'Category set' #you may have another redirect path
end
```

In `routes.rb`

```
post 'update_group_category' => 'products#update_group_category'
```

You may try to place that `update_group_category` action in `admin/product.rb` in `controller` block, but I think keeping it in normal controller is better.

---

Another, probably more user friendly way, is to use js and ajax - you may intercept batch action submit event with

```
$("#collection_selection").submit ->
  if $("#batch_action").val() == "set_category"
    dialog_url = '/products/edit_group_category?'+ $(this).serialize();
    openDialog dialog_url
  false
```

where `openDialog` is some function, that should load required form from `dialog_url` via AJAX and show it in dialog (like [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)). In controller action `edit_group_category` you can access selected products with `Product.where(id: params[:collection_selection])`

As batch action block is being never run in this approach, you may leave just `batch_action :set_category` in `admin/product.rb`

Answer (score 1):

@biomancer had a good answer which I was going to implement and then I discovered that [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/) now has [Batch Action Forms](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/9-batch-actions.md#batch-action-forms); which is much easier!